# Simplify $\def\Arctan{\operatorname{Arctan}}\frac{ \Arctan(\frac{a}{2})}{ \Arctan(\frac{b}{2})}$

Tags: trigonometry

Unfortunately I have not found anything about the rules for this. Is there a way to simplify this?

> $$\def\Arctan{\operatorname{Arctan}}
> \frac{ \Arctan\left(\dfrac{a}{2}\right)}{ \Arctan\left(\dfrac{b}{2}\right)}$$

Comment: ohh, that f(x) was written by habit

Comment: ha. I do that also from time to time.

Comment: I don't think you can get it simplier than that. You could rewrite it using euler formula, but that seem to complicate things instead.

Comment: is there something special about the values of $a,b$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\tan(\frac{\theta}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}) = \sec \theta + \tan \theta$ from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae), if we set $a' = a - \frac{\pi}{2}$, and $b' = b - \frac{\pi}{2}$, then we have:

$$\frac{\sec a' + \tan a'}{\sec b' + \tan b'}$$
$$=\frac{-\csc a - \cot a}{-\csc b - \cot b}$$

Since $\cot(\theta /2) = \csc \theta + \cot \theta$ (from the first link), we have:

$$-\frac{\cot(a/2)}{\cot(b/2)}$$
$$=-\cot(a/2) \tan(b/2)$$

which is about as far as you can possibly get.